# Subwords of a string in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, substring, slice

I am trying to create a list of every possible version of a string in a fast way. I don't really mean specifically subwords - for example from a string *"ABC"*, I want to get:

['C', 'B', 'BC', 'A', 'AB', 'ABC']
(without ***"AC"*** which is a subword)

Same goes for *"123"*:
I want to get ['3', '2', '23', '1', '12', '123'] ***instead of*** ['3', '2', '23', '1', '13', '12', '123']

Comment: define what do you mean by `subwords` more clearly instead of just giving example. People. can interpret different definitions based on their understanding.

Comment: So you just don't want `element[0]+element[-1]` in the final list, or what? And what have you tried so far based on your own research? What went wrong with your attempts? Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with _code_

Comment: [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) would be a good place to start

Comment: `list(set(str[i:j] for i in range(0, len(str)) for j in range(i+1, len(str)+1)))`

Comment: The most common terms for this are **substring** and **subsequence**, with **substring** being the ones you want, ie, substrings = contiguous subsequences. See also: [Difference : subsequences and substrings?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237097/difference-subsequences-and-substrings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple loop and slice based generator function:

```
def subs(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(s)+1):
            yield s[i:j]

>>> list(subs("ABC"))
['A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'B', 'BC', 'C']
```

Comment: Try this on "banana". (Or more simply "aaaa".) Is that the desired result? (Maybe, but seems unlikely.)

Comment: Yes, it is my desired result, however, I'm looking for the fastest way which doesn't take too much space in the memory. For a string like "z"*100000 it takes way too much space - I need it to be less memory taking.

Comment: @trab: why do you want the repetitions? If you do want them, you should *edit your question*. If you don't want them, try the simple expression in my comment.

Comment: This is very space efficient. Just don't put the strings in a list, just process them as you iterate the generator object.

Answer (score 0):

Might be faster to extend the substrings instead of freshly slicing each:

```
def subs(s):
    while s:
        t = ''
        for c in s:
            t += c
            yield t
        s = s[1:]
```

Benchmark results for `s = "z" * 5000`:

```
8.4 seconds  subs_slice
1.5 seconds  subs_extend
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHRaoMwFIbvfYpDbzRThlIGQ/Ci296ijKDxuJ4SE5dEtu7lXdRqLfRALpL/z/@dnHQXd9Jq/9qZYWiMbsFRi@SA2k4bd90FkyK0lCgcaWUXucbvHoOgxgZsX1luJQmMLMsD8NVoAwSkwJTqCyOJyktXbdHPN53iLIHZFGcb21gXQlmDPVJ@/tzw8Nehqlfgz4kkgr1ddVBAGN4BxQi09@kO4gLEA6Bbz6xPsscs9/SmV2Lari9Ott14g8eMppE0mWdaZ0i5SJJ10XgahYe394@QMRYEY9zubwdP8JKm6RTAb4PZb@b5IHd56PxXkSzbqi7z@W9mkmUJpH6pvq3QFBlb7809uWTKe@ZclS1yzjb9smH4Bw)):

```
from timeit import timeit
from collections import deque

def subs_slice(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(s)+1):
            yield s[i:j]

def subs_extend(s):
    while s:
        t = ''
        for c in s:
            t += c
            yield t
        s = s[1:]

funcs = subs_slice, subs_extend

for func in funcs:
    print(list(func('ABCD')))

s = "z" * 5000
for _ in range(3):
    for func in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: deque(func(s), 0), number=1)
        print(t, func.__name__)
    print()
```

Answer (score -1):

For `ABC` you can just get `['C', 'B', 'BC', 'A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'AC']` then use `remove()` to remove the subword from your list. E.i:

```
abc_list = ['C', 'B', 'BC', 'A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'AC']
abc_list.remove('AC')
```

> Output: ['C', 'B', 'BC', 'A', 'AB', 'ABC']

There is a lack of context to the question to give you a full answer. Do all of your strings have 3 characters or more? how do you define what you don't need?
If all the strings are 3 characters in length, then you can use this:

```
def subwording(word: str):
    subword = word[0]+word[2]
    return subword
```

Then you can remove `subword` from your list.

Comment: In a string of `n` characters, there are `n(n+1)/2` substrings and `2**n` subsequences. With `n=30` for instance, that's `435` substrings and `1,073,741,824` subsequences.  You are suggesting to first generate all subsequences, then remove the non-contiguous ones. That would be terribly inefficient.